# Terratest validation using init and plan

Tags: terraform, automated-tests, terraform-provider-aws, terratest

I want to validate the security group inbound and outbound rules for my terraform code using terratest. By only using init and plan (without provisioning)

I have tried using assert.contains to check the string is present inside the plan or not. But I want to specifically check the ports inside ingress and egress as I mentioned in sg.

Comment: Check the release notes for terraform 1.5.0 & 1.6.0 (alpha). https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/releases - cmd: terraform test now exists and in version 1.5.0 there are checks for validating infrastructure. I haven't tested myself yet but plan on to.

Comment: Please see information here (especially about a MCVE) so that we can answer your question: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.